# Can I assume a population is discrete if the probability of each event happening is reasonably high?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

For instance, if I am presented with data that $P(X=50)= 0.1$, $P(X=60)= 0.2$,  $P(X=70)=0.5$, $P(X=80)= 0.2$

Can I assume that it is a discrete distribution, given the fact that if it is a continuous distribution, the probability of each individual event happening would be extremely low?

Comment: In the case of your example the probabilities sum to 1, so you can assume there are no other possible values.

Comment: As @almagest says. If these positive  probabilities would *not* sum up to 1, then you are dealing with a mix of discrete and continuous. In your title the words "discrete" and "population" are linked. I would speak of a "discrete distribution" though, as you do in the body of the question.

Comment: Do you mean that the *empirical* distribution is the one you have given? What is the sample size? If the sample size were 100 and you got a sample like that then yes, I would expect that the distribution is probably discrete or at least has a large discrete part.

Comment: Thanks for the reply guys.

Firstly, is it possible for a population to consist of both discrete and continuous variables?

Let me try to present the question from another angle. Lets say, I do not have any information on the size of the sample. I am only told that p(x=1)= 0.2, p(x=2)=0.5 and p(x=3)=0.1. 

Assuming that I do not have information on what p(x=4) is and how many more variables there are.

With the information that I have, can I assume that the population is discrete?